# Strapi : why data got deleted every time i update strapi-app and deploy it on heroku

Tags: heroku, strapi, heroku-postgres

i've made `strapi app` for my backend and deployed it on `Heroku`

and it works fine

But when i update `strapi app` on local and then push it on `heroku` ,

previous data is deleted , and event admin username and pass is deleted

whay this happen ?

i though this data are on `Postgres data base` that i have made on heroku and should not be deleted

Answer (score -2, accepted):

i found answer

i used **postgres SQL** and its work fine

Comment: @Anubis77 Did you find any solution for this? Its really frustrating if this happens on Live sites.

Comment: @Anubis77 I used POSTGRES for database

Comment: I found the issue later : You need to include the "build" command in your Dockerfile on the CMD line : CMD yarn build && yarn develop. if yarn build is not there it will delete your posts every time you restart the container. So add Build before starting the image.

Comment: this happens in postgres too. you have to include the build command in your dockerfile to stop it deleting your content on image restart.